# How to get Started on django-erp

Tags: python, django, erp

I was going through [this](https://github.com/djangoERPTeam/django-erp) link for django-erp. i successfully created dbs and installed all the requirements. and when i run server and go the browser . the only message i see is `Welcome to django-erp` . How to get started, i don't see much in urls.py too. Is this Project still under construction ?

If so are there any django related rep projects which i can start with . i think writing the entire ERP system from scratch will be useless , cause i think there would be better solutions  than mine. Any Help would be great full

Answer (score 1):

The project is under active construction.

Currently, most of development is visible under the "develop" branch: that's why you can't see almost anything in the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Most open-source projects are under constant development (meaning it is never 'finished').

If you are unfamiliar with Django, you should first work through the tutorials here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/

Also, if you are looking for a ready-built tool, you should perhaps look here:

https://www.djangopackages.com/

Building something from scratch may sound like a waste of time, but it allows you to build the application to your exact specifications (which has its benefits).